# How can I apply filter to an already imported email account in Gmail? 

Tags: gmail

How can I apply filter to an already imported email account in Gmail?  I cannot find any option to do that. Although my imported account has a label, in the filter's options I can't use the label to find all the mails.

Answer (score 4):

When you create filter there is a checkbox next to Create button with text saying "Also apply filter to N matching conversations".

Comment: Please understand - applying the filter to "matching conversations" does not mean the filter is being applied to OLD E-MAIL!

Comment: What does it mean then?